# Telerik auto complete box text changed event using Java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

My requirement is I have 2 controls **Code and description**, when I select the code description will automatically displays and I want to select multiple codes automatically display multiple descriptions in description control and **vice versa**.

For this scenario I am supposed to use "**auto complete box**" using page methods, for the first time I am using Telerik controls.

Now I am able to get Codes in code auto complete box and able to select multiple codes.

Now my question is how to select the description after selecting multiple codes using Java script/jQuery?

My code is like below

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox ID="RdAutoClassCode" runat="server" Width="150" DropDownHeight="150"
            DropDownWidth="150" TokensSettings-AllowTokenEditing="True" OnClientTextChanged="OnClientChange" on>
            <WebServiceSettings Method="GetISOCodesRadCombobox" Path="GetClassCodeAndDescription.aspx" />
        </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>

 function OnClientChange() {
        debugger;
        alert("Hi");
       }
```

Text changed event is not firing using above code.

Please provide any sample for this?

Thanks in advance,
Srividya

Comment: For this u might b using ajax call for description?

Comment: Yes.. I want to know how to call?

Comment: Code would make it clearer, what is the description control? A textbox?

Comment: On document .ready write a function that calls another ajax function. Call that function on blur of the text box... try this if it not works let me know will provide the code

Comment: The description box is also the same rad auto complete box. When I select multiple codes with code auto complete box multiple descriptions will automatically show in description auto complete and **vice versa**..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  finally got the solution.

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox ID="RdAutoClassCode" runat="server" Width="150" DropDownHeight="70"
            OnClientEntryRemoved="RemoveEntry" OnClientEntryAdded="addNewEntry" height="150" DropDownWidth="150"
            TokensSettings-AllowTokenEditing="True">
            <WebServiceSettings Method="GetISOCodesRadCombobox" Path="GetClassCodeAndDescription.aspx" />
        </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>

<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox ID="RdAutoClassDesc" runat="server" Width="150" DropDownHeight="70"
            height="150" DropDownWidth="150" TokensSettings-AllowTokenEditing="True">
            <WebServiceSettings Method="GetISOCodeDescriptionsRadCombobox" Path="GetClassCodeAndDescription.aspx" />
        </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```

**Web Methods:**

```
[WebMethod]
    public static AutoCompleteBoxData GetISOCodesRadCombobox(object context)
    {
        string searchString = ((Dictionary<string, object>)context)["Text"].ToString();
        DataTable data = GetData(searchString, 0);
        List<AutoCompleteBoxItemData> result = new List<AutoCompleteBoxItemData>();

        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            AutoCompleteBoxItemData childNode = new AutoCompleteBoxItemData();
            childNode.Text = row["CodeNumber"].ToString();
            childNode.Value = row["CodeNumber"].ToString();
            result.Add(childNode);
        }

        AutoCompleteBoxData res = new AutoCompleteBoxData();
        res.Items = result.ToArray();

        return res;
    }



[WebMethod]
    public static AutoCompleteBoxData GetISOCodeDescriptionsRadCombobox(object context)
    {
        string searchString = ((Dictionary<string, object>)context)["Text"].ToString();
        DataTable data = GetData(searchString, 1);
        List<AutoCompleteBoxItemData> result = new List<AutoCompleteBoxItemData>();

        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            AutoCompleteBoxItemData childNode = new AutoCompleteBoxItemData();
            childNode.Text = row["CodeDesc"].ToString();
            childNode.Value = row["CodeDesc"].ToString();
            result.Add(childNode);
        }
        AutoCompleteBoxData res = new AutoCompleteBoxData();
        res.Items = result.ToArray();
        return res;
    }


    private static DataTable GetData(string text, int Value)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QMSDBCON"]);
        DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(con, "usp_GetIsoCode", text, Value);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        // adapter.Fill(data);
        data = ds.Tables[0];
        return data;
    }
```

**JavaScript Calling for new entry:**

```
function addNewEntry() {
        debugger;
        var autoCompleteBoxCode = $find("<%= RdAutoClassCode.ClientID %>");
        var autoCompleteBoxDescription = $find("<%= RdAutoClassDesc.ClientID %>");
        var entriesCount = autoCompleteBoxCode.get_entries().get_count();
        var entry = new Telerik.Web.UI.AutoCompleteBoxEntry();
        autoCompleteBoxDescription.get_entries().clear();

        for (var i = 0; i < entriesCount; i++) {
            var code = autoCompleteBoxCode.get_entries().getEntry(i).get_text();
            _ClassCodeSelectedIndexChanged(code);
        }
    }
```

**Calling server method using Json**

```
function _ClassCodeSelectedIndexChanged(code) {
        debugger;
        var URL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
        URL = URL + "/GetClassCodeAndDescription.aspx/GetISOCodesRadComboboxData";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: URL,
                data: "{Code : '" + code + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    onsuccess(msg);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    onerror(xhr);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#textbox").blur(function() {
  ajaxFunction(jQuery("#textbox").val());
});

function ajaxFunction(code){
// Your ajax call
}
```

Try this hopeFully this help.